# What causes ValueError: I/O operation on closed file?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcpy, cost-path

I obtain the following error message:

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Here is my code (It selects each polygon contained in the shapefile "selected_polygons.shp" and builds the least-cost path between the previously selected polygon and each polygon contained in the same shapefile)

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\LCP"
arcpy.env.extent = "costsn.tif"

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("selected_polygons.shp",("*")) as rowsInPatches_start: 

for rowStart in rowsInPatches_start:

    ID_patch_start = int(rowStart[3])

    ## Define SQL expression for the fonction Select Layer By Attribute
    expressionForSelectInPatches_start = "GRIDCODE=%s" % (ID_patch_start) 

    ## Process: Select Layer By Attribute
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("selected_polygons.shp", "Selected_patch_start", expressionForSelectInPatches_start)

    ## Process: Cost Distance
    outCostDist=CostDistance("Selected_patch_start", "costsn.tif", "", "outCostLink.tif")

    ## Save the output
    outCostDist.save("outCostDist.tif")

    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("selected_polygons.shp",("*")) as rowsInSelectedPatches_end: 

        for rowEnd in rowsInSelectedPatches_end:

            ID_patch_end = int(rowEnd[3]) 

            ## Define SQL expression for the fonction Select Layer By Attribute
            expressionForSelectInPatches_end = "GRIDCODE=%s" % (ID_patch_end) 

            ## Process: Select Layer By Attribute in Patches_end
            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("selected_polygons.shp", "Selected_patch_end", expressionForSelectInPatches_end)

            ## Process: Cost Path
            outCostPath = CostPath("Selected_patch_end", "outCostDist.tif", "outCostLink.tif", "EACH_ZONE","FID")

            ## Save the output
            outCostPath.save('P_' +  str(int(ID_patch_start)) + '_' + str(int(ID_patch_end)) + ".tif")

            ## Write in a file .txt
            outfile=open('P_' +  str(int(ID_patch_start)) + '_' + str(int(ID_patch_end)) + ".txt", "w")
            rowsTxt = arcpy.SearchCursor('P_' +  str(int(ID_patch_start)) + '_' + str(int(ID_patch_end)) + ".tif")
            for rowTxt in rowsTxt:
                value = rowTxt.getValue("Value")
                count = rowTxt.getValue("Count")
                pathcost = rowTxt.getValue("PATHCOST")
                startrow = rowTxt.getValue("STARTROW")
                startcol = rowTxt.getValue("STARTCOL")
                print value, count, pathcost, startrow, startcol
                outfile.write(str(value) + " " + str(count) + " " + str(pathcost) + " " + str(startrow) + " " + str(startcol) + "\n")
                outfile.close()
```

Comment: Could you please supply some context?  For example, what does this script do?  What are your thoughts on why this may be happening?  What have you tried to troubleshoot this issue?  Thanks.

Comment: first arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\LCP" should have an r in front of "C:.... ie r"C:\....
second, why is your outfile.close(0 within the loop? it should be outside and only written to when you are done

Comment: I posted a solution below to help with your first problem, which seems to be indentation. However there are other inefficiencies in your code that I'm seeing as well

Comment: Thanks very much Aaron, Dan, and GISKid for your answer. I added an r in front of "C:, I placed outfile.close() at the same level than `for rowTxt in rowsTxt`, and I corrected the indentation. Now It works ! However, strange files (e.g. t_t763.aux.xml, t_t764.aux.xml,...) and folders (e.g. t_t763, t_t764, ...) are created every time that a file. txt is created. I think that this slows my code. Should I post a new question ?

Comment: I would create a smaller subset of your data to test this on until you perfect your code. As for the file names, any idea where this is coming from? You should update your question with the current code you are using (under the former code as an edit) and perhaps add `print` statements to see where those names could be coming from

Comment: Thanks very much GISKid. I added a `print` at each code line and I noted that the strange files and folders appear when I execute the code line `outCostPath = CostPath("Selected_patch_end", "outCostDist.tif", "outCostLink.tif", "EACH_ZONE","FID")`
Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you are getting this particular error is that you are closing your outfile after the first iteration through the following loop:

```
    for rowTxt in rowsTxt:
            value = rowTxt.getValue("Value")
            count = rowTxt.getValue("Count")
            pathcost = rowTxt.getValue("PATHCOST")
            startrow = rowTxt.getValue("STARTROW")
            startcol = rowTxt.getValue("STARTCOL")
            print value, count, pathcost, startrow, startcol
            outfile.write(str(value) + " " + str(count) + " " + str(pathcost) + " " + str(startrow) + " " + str(startcol) + "\n")
            outfile.close()
```

On the next iteration, you are calling the write method on a file that you just closed.
You need to move your outfile.close() statement outside of that loop:

```
    for rowTxt in rowsTxt:
            value = rowTxt.getValue("Value")
            count = rowTxt.getValue("Count")
            pathcost = rowTxt.getValue("PATHCOST")
            startrow = rowTxt.getValue("STARTROW")
            startcol = rowTxt.getValue("STARTCOL")
            print value, count, pathcost, startrow, startcol
            outfile.write(str(value) + " " + str(count) + " " + str(pathcost) + " " + str(startrow) + " " + str(startcol) + "\n")
     outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation is wrong for the first for loop, try this:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\LCP"
arcpy.env.extent = "costsn.tif"

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("selected_polygons.shp",("*")) as rowsInPatches_start:

    for rowStart in rowsInPatches_start:
```